# Nuxt 3 - 404 Page Not Found Error and H3Error Page not found

Tags: nuxt.js

Whenever a user visits a non existing page I get in the logs the following error which I would rather not log for every not found page.

> [nuxt] error caught during app initialization H3Error: Page not found: /.git/config
> at createError (file:///var/www/site1/.output/server/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:128:15)
> at file:///var/www/site1/.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:2154:47
> at triggerAfterEach (file:///var/www/site1/.output/server/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs:3306:13)
> at file:///var/www/site1/.output/server/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs:3209:13
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at file:///var/www/site1/.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:2170:7
> at createNuxtAppServer (file:///var/www/site1/.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:19902:7)
> at Object.renderToString (file:///var/www/site1/.output/server/node_modules/vue-bundle-renderer/dist/runtime.mjs:172:19)
> at file:///var/www/site1/node_modules/nuxt/dist/core/runtime/nitro/renderer.mjs:128:21
> at file:///var/www/site1/node_modules/nitropack/dist/runtime/renderer.mjs:12:22 {
> statusCode: 404,
> fatal: false,
> unhandled: false,
> statusMessage: 'Page not found: /.git/config',
> __nuxt_error: true
> }

I tried to create a plugin in plugins folder named errorhandler.ts with this code but its not logging anything

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.config.errorHandler = (error, context) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(context);
  };
});
```

This is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-q2rvlp?file=plugins%2Ferrorhandler.ts.

Can anyone share some thoughts about handling not found error in Nuxt 3 and even creating a custom  404 page?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. The 404 error messages were logged even when the  404 errors were handled by an error.vue. After a lot of searching and trying, I created a little Nitro 'plugin' which marks the h3Error as handled before calling the default error handler. This works because an error is only logged if it's marked unhandled or fatal (see source code: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/blob/f84df08dbcab675a8419c42cc5c2a5258df37bff/packages/nuxt/src/core/runtime/nitro/error.ts#LL28C36-L28C36)

My code in /server/plugins.error.ts:

```
import type { H3Error, H3Event } from 'h3'

export default defineNitroPlugin((nitroApp) => {
    const h3OnError = nitroApp.h3App.options.onError;
    nitroApp.h3App.options.onError = (error : Error, event : H3Event) => {
        let h3error : H3Error = error as H3Error;
        
        if(h3error?.statusCode === 404)
        {
            h3error.unhandled = false;
        }

        if(h3OnError !== undefined)
        {
            return h3OnError(error, event);
        }
        return;
    };
})
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Error handling [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling#error-handling),

"You can customize this error page by adding `~/error.vue` in the source directory of your application, alongside app.vue. This page has a single prop - `error` which contains an error for you to handle."

Here is an example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-q97lbh?file=error.vue

Comment: Thank you for your answer still in logs H3Error is not handled any thoughts on that? Also I would like to ask you If you have any idea why the plugin is not logging anything?

Comment: I don't think we can hide the H3errors that are showing on the terminal log as I think it is an error response which we can use it dynamically to render on the page based on the response given. e.g. If you want to dynamically show what type of statusCode the error type is, you can use the `error.status` from the `error` object props.  Hope that make sense. I also updated the `error.vue` file Check it out and my explanation will make more sense.  As for the plugin, have you tried using the `app:error`? Visit the stackblitz example I sent above and check the `plugins` folder.

Comment: Here is the full error handling example from Nuxt. 
https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/app/error-handling

Comment: **Edit on my first comment**. On stackblitz, the  h3Error will display but when you use vs code, the H3Error will not show anymore. I tried it with the `nuxtApp.hook('app:error')`.

Comment: Your stackblitz fork gives a 503 error!! It this how it should be?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added the error.ts and error.vue in my project. But the H3Error is still in the logs, at least when running with npm run dev.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also still playing with this error handling, here is my fetcher on the [id].vue file.

```
const { id } = useRoute().params

const { data: student, error } = await useMyFetch<IStudentApplicationDetail>(
  `/api/member-student-application/${id}`
)

if (error.value) {
  throw createError({ statusCode: 404, statusMessage: 'Page Not Found' })
}
```

Here is my error.ts plugins

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.config.errorHandler = (error, context) => {
    console.log(' ~ file: error.ts:6 ~ defineNuxtPlugin ~ context:', context)
    console.log(' ~ file: error.ts:6 ~ defineNuxtPlugin ~ error:', error)
  }
})
```

With this error handling, I got the console log on the server side. Here is the full error

```
 ~ file: error.ts:6 ~ defineNuxtPlugin ~ context: {}                                                               23:28:22
 ~ file: error.ts:6 ~ defineNuxtPlugin ~ error: H3Error: Page Not Found                                            23:28:22
    at Module.createError (file:///Users/januarfonti/Code/Clearview/asifa/asifa-member-fe/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:128:15)
    at Module.createError (/Users/januarfonti/Code/Clearview/asifa/asifa-member-fe/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/composables/error.js:37:38)
    at setup (/Users/januarfonti/Code/Clearview/asifa/asifa-member-fe/pages/admin/members/student-applications/view/[id].vue:43:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  statusCode: 404,
  fatal: false,
  unhandled: false,
  statusMessage: 'Page Not Found',
  __nuxt_error: true
}
```

I'm not sure if it's a good error handler since I still got another error instead of only the console.log